# injecting a JavaScript after Ext.OnReady () event

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add a javascript to the page dynamically after Ext.on.Ready() in Extjs4. In other words something similar to  jQuery's getScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The private Ext.Loader.injectScriptElement/loadScriptFile method can be used to load an external JS file.

refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Loader.html#Ext-Loader-method-injectScriptElement)

check [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-152742.html?s=438baf52ec060e56249772756062136b)

Answer (score 4):

I would probably naively suggest just inserting a script tag into the page (because that's what I would do)

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.async = 'async'; //if you like
script.src = 'some/url/here';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item();
head.appendChild(script)
```

At least, that would work for now.

That's as opposed to doing something like this:

```
Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"myScript.js\"></script>");
```

Naturally, I intend that you would put this code inside your onReady event handler.